# Не компилируется проект

Tags: c#, компиляция

Не компилируется проект в MSVS2015 под .NET Framework 4.5.
Судя по всему компилятор не понимает выражения C#6.0 с членами, переходящими в выражения. Если для этого нужен компилятор Roslyn, то как его установить/задать в студии? Или я не в ту сторону копаю и проблема в чем-то другом?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ссылка на проект: https://github.com/yarseyah/sentinel

Код который не компилируется:

```
    private void AddCopyCommandBinding()
    {
        void Handler(object s, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs a)
        {
            CopySelectedLogEntries();
        }

        var command = new RoutedCommand("Copy", typeof(GridView));
        command.InputGestures.Add(new KeyGesture(Key.C, ModifierKeys.Control, "Copy"));
        messages.CommandBindings.Add(new CommandBinding(command, Handler));

        try
        {
            Clipboard.SetData(DataFormats.Text, string.Empty);
        }
        catch (COMException)
        {
        }
    }
```

Comment: К прочтению: [Мой сайт/проект не работает. Можно я просто дам на него ссылку?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5263/178779)

Comment: Код должен быть кодом, текст ошибки - текстом. Это правила сайта.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, очевидно же, что в данном случае это не требуется.

Comment: Поищи language version в свойствах проекта.

Comment: @Qwertiy не очевидно...

Comment: @PavelMayorov, почему же? Если код верный и проблема описана в вопросе текстом?

Comment: @Qwertiy блин, не увидел. В таком случае нужно убрать нафиг скриншот и ссылку, иначе вопрос так и будет собирать минусы.

Comment: @PavelMayorov  Что останется, если убрать скрин и ссылку? Я же написал в вопросе, что не знаю в чем дело и это только предположение

Comment: @PavelMayorov, ссылка действительно не нужна, а скриншот я бы для наглядности оставил. Подредактируешь?

Comment: @Qwertiy, в language version установил c# 6.0, ошибки такие же

Comment: @swd потому что это седьмая версия языка, а не шестая

Comment: @PavelMayorov, скажите, пожалуйста, что нужно установить для того, что бы переключиться на седьмую версию языка? В настройках проекта в версии языка c# 6.0 - это самая последняя версия, которую могу выбрать. В вопрос добавил одну из функций, которая не компилируется, с её синтаксисом не знаком. Можете объяснить как работает Handler? Выглядит как функция в функции...

Comment: 2017ю студию надо установить...

Comment: @PavelMayorov, Спасибо! Все оказалось проще, чем казалось

Comment: Не надо исправлять заголовок, чтобы изменить статус вопроса. Просто напишите ответ на свой же вопрос и отметьте его решением.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/43048660/2856962

> Можно заменить компилятор, поставляемый с Visual Studio на версию,
>   поддерживающую C#7, установив Nuget-пакет [Microsoft.Net.Compilers](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Net.Compilers/)

Но, как пишет автор ответа, студия по прежнему будет подчёркивать неизвестные ей конструкции. Хотя код будет компилироваться.

Answer (score 1):

Необходимо установить Visual Studio 2017.